# How to bind variables of two classes in C#?

Tags: c#, list, binding, two-way

I have two similar classes in C#

```
public class Property
{
    public string version;               
    public string CCodeName { get; set; }
    public string CDoc { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyFieldsInExcel
{
    public string ShortNames { get; set; }
    public string CNames { get; set; }
    public string CDoc { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }        
}
```

After this I have created two lists.

```
static List<PropertyFieldsInExcel> listA = new List<PropertyFieldsInExcel>();
public List<Property> listB = new List<Property>();
```

Now, I want to have a two-way binding between these two lists. As in, whenever something changes in `listA` the corresponding element in `listB` must get updated.

Like if, `listA[i].ShortName = "abc"` then `listB[i].ShortName` also must have the same value.
`listA.Add()` should trigger `listB.Add()` and vice versa.

Thank you!

Comment: I do not have any idea how to proceed. I'm kind of amateur in C#. Any kind of solution is acceptable to me.

Answer (score 3):

Like @Amir said, you have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Class,

and your case is the exact example from: [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15822/Bind-Better-with-INotifyPropertyChanged)

You should have a try on this example.

Comment: I went through the code in the link. Similar code would work if I had just two classes to be bound. But I have to bind a list of objects and also insert or add just like lists. That is where I'm facing issues.

Comment: Mhm did you tried to change the Lists to ObservableCollections because they automatically update if an Object removes add etc. here is a similar question how to sync two observable collections: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2e278e3c-27ab-42b5-8a7b-6828ddbb9caf/how-to-sync-two-observable-collection-?forum=wpf

Answer (score -1):

Implement `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged`-Interface in your classes and use `PropertyChanged` event handler to make corresponding changes in your classes.
Use `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<>` instead of list.